# ubuntu crashes after login [ apport-gtk[3816] : segfault... in libgtk-3.so.0.2404.29

Tags: crash

Please help, I have been using ubuntu on my vmware for 2 years. Multiple screens working very robuust. So I am very pleased working this way.
Not sure when it started but whenever I login ubuntu crashes. See screenshot.

[screen after crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qzkB.png)